# Django rest framework listfield valid integer is required formdata

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, multipartform-data

I am trying to make a post request on model with many to many field

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    price = models.FloatField()
    attribute_values = models.ManyToManyField(Value)
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True)
```

My serializer class:

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    categories = serializers.ListField(child=serializers.IntegerField())
    attribute_values = serializers.ListField(child=serializers.IntegerField())

    def create(self, validated_data):
        categories = validated_data.pop('categories')
        attribute_values = validated_data.pop('attribute_values')
        product = Product.objects.create(**validated_data)

        for cat_id in categories:
            category = Category.objects.get(pk=cat_id)
            product.categories.add(category)

        for value_id in attribute_values:
           value = Value.objects.get(pk=value_id)
           product.attribute_values.add(value)

       product.save()
       return product

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'description', 'price', 'quantity', 'categories', 'image', 'attribute_values')
```

I am making post request with form data, as it contains image:

```
var formData = new FormData()
let cats = Object.keys(selectedCategories).map(id => Number(id))

formData.append('image', blob)
formData.append('categories', cats)
formData.append('attribute_values', attributes)
formData.append('name', name)
formData.append('description', description)
formData.append('quantity', quantity)
formData.append('price', 100)
```

However, the server responds with this error:

```
 {"categories":{"0":["A valid integer is required."]},"attribute_values":{"0":["A valid integer is required."]}}
```

How do i make the server accept the array of integers with the form data, as it seems for me that on the client side everything is correct. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The serializer manual field 'categories' is not correct. You can erase this line and allow to DRF generate an automatic field or use [primarykeyrelatedfield](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield)